# How to call a different parse function from the main parse function in Scrapy?

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I am quite new to Scrapy (actually this is my first time using it). I am parsing a page that has the full cast of a TV show and I'm trying to gather some information for each actor that only exists in the actor's personal page.

Here is a snippet of my parse function:

```
for actor in response.css('tr.even'):
    .
    .
    .
    .
    yield {
              'real_name':
              ' '.join(actor.css('td.itemprop a span.itemprop::text').extract_first().split()),

              'character_name':
              ' '.join(actor.css('td.character a::text').extract_first().split()),

              'imdb_link': link,

              'show': show,

              'pic': scrapy.Request(url=link, callback=self.parse_pic)
   }
```

For the pic parameter, I want to open the url stored in link, and then run `response.css('td div.image a img::attr(src)').extract_first()` to get back a link to the actor's picture

Here is my parse_pic function:

```
def parse_pic(self, response):
    return response.css('td div.image a img::attr(src)').extract_first()
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Now you create a request but you are not performing it. I'd suggest to store the data you've collected in the meta data of the new request.

Request 1: create a new request for the pic, store all data from the 1st url in the meta data, send a new request with the pic url

Request 2: collect data (from meta) from request 1 and complement this data with the pic data.

```
for actor in response.css('tr.even'):
    .
    .
    .
    .
    request = scrapy.Request(url=link, callback=self.parse_pic)
    request.meta['data'] = {
              'real_name':
              ' '.join(actor.css('td.itemprop a span.itemprop::text').extract_first().split()),

              'character_name':
              ' '.join(actor.css('td.character a::text').extract_first().split()),

              'imdb_link': link,

              'show': show,
   }
   yield request
```

And then this as parse_pic:

```
   def parse_pic(self, response):
     data = response.meta.get('data')
     data['pic'] = response.css('td div.image a img::attr(src)').extract_first()
     yield data
```